# Knowledge Articles opened from Case Deflection are not showing full screen

Tags: community

I have Case Deflection setup on my Community.  All is working except for when a user actually clicks on a Knowledge Article.  The KA is not showing full screen...it's only showing my part of the KA.   See pic.

The KA will appear in a popu...but it's getting cutoff.
How can I get this to show the entire KA?

[image]